# SELECT statement for fetching values from multiple Priority Queues

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm using an Oracle DB table to store orders that can have multiple events, and each of them has to be processed sequentially based on a `version` field.

The basic structure of this table contains 3 columns: `Order ID`; the aforementioned `Version`; and `Processed`, a simple 1/0 `boolean` flag to know if an order version was processed or not.

The processing of said orders is performed on batch, so what I'm struggling with it's writing a `SELECT` statement that gets, for each Order ID, the next unprocessed version on a single result set.

Does anybody have any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Which version of the database?

Comment: You can try this method to ouput to the file with echo or print the result on a loop.

how to store output of sql query in variable in batch script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891606/how-to-store-output-of-sql-query-in-variable-in-batch-script

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/425ba/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(version) , field1, field2
FROM t 
WHERE processed = 0 
GROUP BY ID, field1, field2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/425ba/2/0)**:

```
| ID | MIN(VERSION) |               FIELD1 |               FIELD2 |
|----|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 |            2 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  2 |            5 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select id, version, processed, field1, field2 from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/425ba/2/1)**:

```
| ID | VERSION | PROCESSED |               FIELD1 |               FIELD2 |
|----|---------|-----------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 |       1 |         1 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  1 |       2 |         0 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  1 |       3 |         0 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  2 |       5 |         0 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  2 |      10 |         0 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
|  3 |       4 |         1 | field1 char(20)      | field2 char(20)      |
```

BTW, don't forget to add a B-TREE index on `(processed,version)`, it'll help for this query ;)

Comment: Great! That worked flawlessly. 
I'll add just one thing: my real data included other fields, so I've finally used SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id, version) in (SELECT id, MIN(version) FROM table WHERE processed = 0 GROUP BY id), which is some tuple-magic I wasn't aware of in SQL.
I'm not very SQL-savvy (as you might have noticed), so can I ask why it's important to index that tuple in particular?

Comment: @gnzlrm avoid the `in(select)` if you can, it's usually a disaster for performance... I've edited my answer with other fields. Index allow the DB engine to only load the index for the "search" part of your query you save him a load of **all** the data of that table.

Comment: Oh, sorry I wasn't clear enough when detailing. Some of the extra columns, say `amount`, can differ from one `version` to another. I'd have to take the amount from the candidate row, which is what's achieved by using the `in (SELECT)`. Is there any other way to get this without a performance issue?

Comment: I've noticed that the addition of field on the GROUP BY clause can have the same benefit, but isn't that optimal than the `in (SELECT)` up to some point? 'cause I've more than 20 amendable fields. It's still more efficient to do a GROUP BY with all those fields?

Comment: @gnzlrm ok, never-mind, I can't find again the way I was doing them. Go with the `IN (select)`, oracle will optimize it as he can. If you really have some performance issue, post again here, you'll have your answer ;)